# Laravel custom validation message parameter

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm using laravel 5.1. I have a summernotejs form element. I've created a custom validation rule successfully, which takes the HTML provided from the form input, strips the tags, and does a `strlen()` call on the text content. Therefore I can see the length of a message without any tags in it.

This is my validation rule:

```
Validator::extend('strip_min', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    return strlen(strip_tags($value)) >= $parameters[0];
});
```

I call the validation rule by specifying: `strip_min:10` or `strip_min:20` etc, with the number being the minimum string length after stripping tags.

I want to add a custom message, saying that the content lengths needs to be a minimum of `n` characters long.

The Laravel documentation on this aspect is useless. I've opened my `validation.php` file, which contains all the error messages.

I've added the key `strip_min` to the message array, with the message: `The :attribute must be at least :min characters.`

When I test it, I get the error message:

```
The notice must be at least :min characters.
```

How can I convert `:min` into the number specified in the validation rule?! I've [read the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-validation-rules) but it's all over the place, and I cant understand how to just simply replace :min with the given number.

Answer (score 20):

Found out.

```
Validator::extend('strip_min', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {

    $validator->addReplacer('strip_min', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters){
        return str_replace([':min'], $parameters, $message);
    });

    return strlen(strip_tags($value)) >= $parameters[0];
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this in validation.php file

```
    'strip_min' => 'The :attribute must be at least :strip_min characters.'
```