# Laravel validation modify request before validation. return original if failed

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a WYSIWYG editor. When users keep pressing space in the editor, the input will be like this.

```
"<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</p>"
```

To prevent this I modified the `all` method in Request class like this to remove whitespace and tags.

```
public function all()
{
    $input = parent::all();

    $input['body'] = strip_tags(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', str_replace('&nbsp;',"", $input['body'])));
    //modify input here

    return $input;
}
```

This works great.

However, the problem here is if other validation rules fail, the return value from `old` helper function is modified by the method.

So, if the original input is like this

```
"""
<p>&nbsp;<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Mb5xcH9PcI0" width="560" height="314" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></p>\r\n
<p>This is the body.</p>
"""
```

And if other validation rules fail I get this as an old input.

`"Thisisthebody."`

So, is there any way to get original request inputs as an old input when validations failed?

Here is my form request.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\Factory as ValidationFactory;

class ArticleRequest extends Request
{

public function all()
{
    $input = parent::all();

    $input['body'] = strip_tags(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', str_replace('&nbsp;',"", $input['body'])));
    //modify input here

    return $input;
}

/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required|min:3|max:40',
        'tags.*' => 'required',
        'body'  => 'required|min:50',
        //up to 6mb
        'thumbnail'=>'image|file|max:10240'
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
   return [
        'title.required'  => 'タイトルを入力してください',
        'title.min'  => 'タイトルは３文字以上でお願いします',
        'title.max'  => 'タイトルは40文字以下でお願いします',
        'body.min'  => '本文は50文字以上お書きください',
        'body.required'  => '本文を入力してください',
        'tags.*.required'  => 'タグを選んでください',
        'thumbnail.image'  => '画像の形式はjpeg, bmp, png, svgのいずれかをアップロードできます',
        'thumbnail.file'  => 'フォームから画像をもう一度アップロードしてください',
        'thumbnail.max'  => 'ファイルは10MBまでアップロードできます',
   ];
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could backup the original value before modifying it? `$input['original_body'] = $input['body'];` and then try to fallback to `original_body` in your view? I know my idea smells, I'm just trying to ignite some thoughts here.

Comment: Use `session()` to do it? That could be an option. Let me see if somebody has some other solutions. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: ping me if something smarts comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom validator which strips the tags, counts characters but does not modify the content itself.

```
Validator::extend('strip_min', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {

    $validator->addReplacer('strip_min', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters){
        return str_replace([':min'], $parameters, $message);
    });

    return strlen(
        strip_tags(
            preg_replace(
                '/\s+/', 
                '', 
                str_replace('&nbsp;',"", $value)
            )
        )
    ) >= $parameters[0];
});
```

and in your `validation.php` lang file add:

```
'strip_min' => 'The :attribute must be at least :strip_min characters.'
```

[source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33414725/2119863](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33414725/2119863)